# SiteMapProvider practice: load all?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitemap

I'm using a custom sitemapprovider (SQL) which enables me to add the pages from the database. I also have a node called `products`. There are several `categories` which contain other categories *or* products.

I currently load ALL products and categories in the sitemap. (along with products there are more business objects which have a custom subnode-structure). **Is this good practice?**

(goal is to be able to use SiteMap.CurrentNode *and* breadcrumbs)

*p.s. I have security-trimming turned off and i implement a custom authentication method and custom trimming in my navigation menu.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course.

Why wouldn't you want to link to all the pages in your site?

Comment: True, however I have two issues. 1.) I use localized page titles in an SQL resource. Is it correct to extend the SiteMapNode and override the Title property? 2.) I have over 1 million articles and newsmessages which should have breadcrumb/SiteMap.currentNode functionality. Should I load all of them?